# Number with only 2 decimal digits in Model(no view helpers)-rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i know that i can use number_with_precision(View helper) in my view/controller.now i have a code in my model for generating pdf(Prawn gem) that has a table having all values with only 2 decimal digits.i have used

```
"%.2f" %@fee
```

to show fee with precision of 2.is there any other method so that i can show the `@fee` with the same **precision of 2** as i used above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try it with:

```
a,b = @fee.to_s.split(".")
@fee = a + "." + b.ljust(2, "0")
```

Comment: @Lichtamberg...i have already tried ,it works fine for number with decimal place of more than 2,but what if number has a decimal of only one.for example. `1.9.2-p290 :038 > a=1245.4
 => 1245.4
1.9.2-p290 :039 > a.round(2)
 => 1245.4 `
1.9.2-p290 :040 > a.round(2).to_s
 => "1245.4"

Comment: still getting the same output when i tried in irb.example:-  `1.9.2-p290 :057 > a=1245.4
 => 1245.4 
1.9.2-p290 :058 > a.round(2).to_s.ljust(2, "0")
 => "1245.4" `